# OR-Tools: how to define node that not possible to visit in VRP/CVRP/VRPTW?

Tags: or-tools

im trying this [vrp example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp#model) 
From my understanding, we must have 2d array to define distance matrix between all nodes 
But for my demand, there is few nodes wont have distance matrix between, like this graph

[image]

The distance matrix array will be:

```java
public final long[][] distanceMatrix = {
         {0, 2, 1, 0, 0},
         {0, 0, 0, 2, 1},
         {0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  };
```

The issue is that for the distance matrix array, we must have `int` number between all nodes, so for two nodes that dont have direct path between (like A->D) i use `0`, but OrTool will understand the cost to travel between those two nodes is zero. and the solver always choose that path to go. 
So is there any support from ortool library to declare this kind on directional graph? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To forbid an arc you have basically two ways:

1. Using a Distance Dimension and a value above the vehicle max capacity.
   e.g. suppose you have a distance dimension:

```py
transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

routing.AddDimension(
  transit_callback_index,
  0, # no slack for distance, can be use as waiting time for Time dimension
  42,  # maximum distance a vehicle can travel
  True,  # force start cumul to zero, i.e. vehicle start a km 0
  "Distance"
)
...
```

As you can see, here `42` is the limit for vehicles SO if in your distance matrix you use `43` no vehicle could take this arc since it is above the vehicle capacity (ed above the upper bound of the CumulVar domain).
Thus you could write your distance matrix as:

```py
public final long[][] distanceMatrix = {
         {43, 2, 1,43,43},
         {43,43,43, 2, 1},
         {43, 1,43,43,43},
         {43,43,43,43, 3},
         {43, 3,43,43,43},
  };
```

note: your `SetArcCost()` and `AddDimension()` can use the same registered evaluator.

2. You can set the list of allowed next nodes.
   For each node you can define a list a allowed nodes (by default all nodes)
   e.g. here you have:

```py
next = {
  [A, [B, C]],
  [B, [E, D]],
  [C, [B]],
  [D, [E]],
  [E, []]}
```

note(instead of A-E you must use 0-4)

Then you can use:

```py
for node, l in next:
  node_index = manager.NodeToIndex(node)
  next_indices = [node_index] # need itself in case node is dropped
  for next_node in l:
    next_indices.append(manager.NodeToIndex(next_node))
  routing.NextVar(node_index).SetValues(next_indices)
```

Comment: thanks @Mizux
i will try. 
What if i use the max distance of all nodes to set for forbidden path?
Like sume of all distances in my example is 10. then i will set all forbid path = 10 (or even 11)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 0, I would try to initialize those nodes with an unaffordable cost, eg  int64.Maxvalue